# Travis CI does not find header files

Tags: c++, cmake, travis-ci

Basically I wanted to learn CMake and GTest. On top of that I wanted to try out CI's and I have added my simple project to Travis CI and AppVeyor. The project compiles well on my local machine (tested with vs 2017 and g++, not sure about the versions, because I am not near it at the moment) as well as on AppVeyor.

The project consists of a few headers compiled to a static library, executable for "manual testing" the static library and gtest (no tests at the moment, just a template). 
The structure looks like that:

```
.
+-- .appveyor.yml
+-- .travis.yml
+-- CMakeLists.txt
+-- main
|   +-- main.cpp [The manual testing exec]
|   +-- CMakeLists.txt
+-- include
|   +-- Utility.h
|   +-- CMakeLists.txt
|   +-- Other header files to compile to static library
+-- test
|   +-- CMakeLists.txt
|   +-- CMakeLists.txt.in
|   +-- testutility
|   |   +-- main.cpp [sample exe file for gtest, not used yet]
|   |   +-- CMakeLists.txt
```

During build on Travis CI, it cannot find headers for the static library. 
I have tried using 
`include_directories(".")` on main CMakeLists.

Main CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.1)
project (primlibrary)

enable_testing()

include_directories(".")

add_subdirectory(include)
add_subdirectory(main)
add_subdirectory(test)
```

Travis CI error message

```
CMake Error at include/CMakeLists.txt:12 (add_library):
  Cannot find source file:
    Utility.h
  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/travis/build/SoIAS/PrimLibrary/build
The command "cmake .." exited with 1.
$ make
Scanning dependencies of target prim_library
[  9%] Linking CXX static library libprim_library.a
[  9%] Built target prim_library
Scanning dependencies of target manualtestingapp
[ 18%] Building CXX object main/CMakeFiles/manualtestingapp.dir/main.cpp.o
/home/travis/build/SoIAS/PrimLibrary/main/main.cpp:2:29: fatal error: include/Utility.h: No such file or directory
 #include "include/Utility.h"
```

And include/CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14) 
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON) 
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF) 

set(prim_library_srcs  
  ForwardList.h 
  LinkedList.h 
  Utility.h 
  tempfix.cpp 
) 

add_library(prim_library STATIC ${prim_library_srcs}) 
set_target_properties(prim_library PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX) 

target_include_directories(prim_library PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

CI and git links: 
- [Travis CI last build](https://travis-ci.org/SoIAS/PrimLibrary/builds/364032111)
- [Appveyor build](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/SoIAS/primlibrary/build/1.0.8)
- [Github](https://github.com/SoIAS/PrimLibrary/tree/app_veyor)

Do you know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: According to the Stack Overflow rules, question post should include the error message, and the code related to it. Please, [edit] your question post by adding error message to it, and some code (probably, from one of your `CMakeLists.txt`) which should eliminate the error (by your opinion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved literally a dozen minutes after posting. The Utility.h file locally had capitalized first letter while the one on git was lower case. It was solved by using git command to capitalize the first letter of the file on git:
`git mv include/utility.h include/Utility.h`

Comment: Stupid mistake I was fighting since yesterday, because I was only checking the file names locally instead of on git.